# EF6 Many-to-many can not delete

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, cascading-deletes

I have created table using EF6 core using below code.

**The problem is**, UserA , UserB created and assigned the different claims. No issue at all. When assigning existing claims (for example UserB is assigned UserA's claims --> **[tying to do]** delete UserB's claims & Changing UserB's subject to UserA's subject) then I am deleting UserB's claim by subjectId this create the primary key duplicate issue in UserUserClaims tables bcos SubjectId and ClaimId already existing

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Subject { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; } = new List<UserClaim>();

    public List<UserClaimRelation> UserClaimRelations { get; set; }
}


public class UserClaim 
{

    [Key]
    public Guid UserClaimId { get; set; } 

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Type{ get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public Guid Subject { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public List<UserClaimRelation> UserClaimRelations { get; set; }
}

public class UserClaimRelation
{
        public Guid UserClaimId{ get; set; }
        public UserClaim Claim { get; set; }

        public Guid UserSubject{ get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
}


public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Claims)
            .WithMany(p => p.Users)
            .UsingEntity<UserClaimRelation>(
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Claim)
                    .WithMany(t => t.UserClaimRelations)
                    .HasPrincipalKey(f => f.UserClaimId),
                j => j.HasOne(p => p.User)
                    .WithMany(t => t.UserClaimRelations)
                    .HasPrincipalKey( t => t.Subject),
                j => j.HasKey( t => new {t.UserClaimId, t.UserSubject})
            );
}
```

I am trying to delete the Claims by SubjectId

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteUserClaimsBySubjectAsync(Guid subject)
{
            if (subject == Guid.Empty)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subject));
            }
            
        var claims = await _context.UserClaims
                .Where(x => x.Subject == subject).ToListAsync();
            

            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
               _context.UserClaims.Remove(claim);    
            }

            //_context.UserClaims.RemoveRange(claims);

            return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0);
}
```

While deleting claims in **DeleteUserClaimsBySubjectAsync** I am getting the below error

SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UserClaimRelation'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserClaimRelation'. The duplicate key value is (13229d33-99e0-41b3-b18d-4f72127e3971, 8acbbd40-1608-41f2-de59-08d9b58b83d3).

**SQL Profiler Query**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [UserClaimRelation] ([UserClaimId], [UserSubject])
VALUES (@p0, @p1),
(@p2, @p3),
(@p4, @p5),
(@p6, @p7),
(@p8, @p9);
DELETE FROM [UserClaims]
WHERE [UserClaimId] = @p10 AND [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p11;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [UserClaims]
WHERE [UserClaimId] = @p12 AND [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p13;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [UserClaims]
WHERE [UserClaimId] = @p14 AND [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p15;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [UserClaims]
WHERE [UserClaimId] = @p16 AND [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p17;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM [UserClaims]
WHERE [UserClaimId] = @p18 AND [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p19;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 uniqueidentifier,@p3 uniqueidentifier,@p4 uniqueidentifier,@p5 uniqueidentifier,@p6 uniqueidentifier,@p7 uniqueidentifier,@p8 uniqueidentifier,@p9 uniqueidentifier,@p10 uniqueidentifier,@p11 nvarchar(4000),@p12 uniqueidentifier,@p13 nvarchar(4000),@p14 uniqueidentifier,@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 uniqueidentifier,@p17 nvarchar(4000),@p18 uniqueidentifier,@p19 nvarchar(4000)',

@p0='6203BBC3-BD52-4E32-3DDD-08D9B86AB745',@p1='D860EFCA-22D9-47FD-8249-791BA61B07C7',
@p2='80B958C5-FF44-400F-3DDE-08D9B86AB745',@p3='D860EFCA-22D9-47FD-8249-791BA61B07C7',
@p4='A844CB59-5A00-488A-3DDF-08D9B86AB745',@p5='D860EFCA-22D9-47FD-8249-791BA61B07C7',@p6='794AB806-3215-45AF-3DE0-08D9B86AB745',@p7='D860EFCA-22D9-47FD-8249-791BA61B07C7',@p8='80EFF0DF-AE56-419A-3DE1-08D9B86AB745',@p9='D860EFCA-22D9-47FD-8249-791BA61B07C7',@p10='1A48CF6E-E1CD-4042-3DE4-08D9B86AB745',@p11=N'742674d8-3c59-4be4-ac09-38c6804acb66',@p12='258ABD95-6B2A-45CC-3DE6-08D9B86AB745',@p13=N'd206316a-71af-46b7-92e4-bddca669ad87',@p14='4FB1D2E3-18BE-4AFC-3DE3-08D9B86AB745',@p15=N'3eb17fb7-998b-47e1-a97f-3640cbd82b7a',@p16='6C2B9A18-5C8F-4068-3DE5-08D9B86AB745',@p17=N'415b2cc1-b50a-4ec8-872d-13b6342dcd33',@p18='951CEEA6-D057-4588-3DE2-08D9B86AB745',@p19=N'3dfd76dd-d515-4daa-893c-f1ae97aa063a'
```

Comment: How did you populate those tables? It looks like EF wants to populate the join table on your way to delete - did you populate it manually somehow? If so, try to assign claims by using EF, load user and add a claim. Then after saving, try to delete it.

Comment: In the source you can see the **UserClaimRelation** & **MyDbContext** code to populate the relationship. I dont understand while deleting from UserClaims why its inserting to UserClaimRelation, any idea on this?

Comment: Join not on `.HasPrincipalKey( t => t.Subject)` but on .HasPrincipalKey( t => t.UserClaimId) - this should help. You can still delete by searching for proper subject.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want many-to-many relationship here - multiple user can have multiple different claims and multiple claims can be assigned to multiple users.

So first - `User`s:

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Subject { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; } = new List<UserClaim>();
}
```

Then, `UserClaim`s

```
public class UserClaim 
{

    [Key]
    public Guid UserClaimId { get; set; } 

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Type{ get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public Guid Subject { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that there is no navigation property leading to `UserClaimRelation` in any of the above. In the matter of fact, we remove this `UserClaimRelation` as an separate entity model entirely - it is not needed for this example. You can map it if you really want, but lets focus on making this work.

Now, the relationship setup:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Claims)
        .WithMany(x => x.Users)
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "UserClaimRelation",
            x => x.HasOne<User>().WithMany(),
            x => x.HasOne<UserClaim>().WithMany(),
            x => x.ToTable("UserClaimRelation"));
}
```

Now, after updating / recreating / reapplying migrations to the database (depends on your way of doing things) you should be able to delete the claims by subject without modifying your `DeleteUserClaimsBySubjectAsync` method.

This should set it all up and create intermediary table.
**Validate** this code, I was typing from memory

Comment: pls check my below session as answer. your solution is not working. Please note that I am updating userA **Subject** with UserB so both userA and UserB has **same subject**

Comment: Ok, but it should not be a problem, since subject is not a key or foreign key anywhere, right? Therefore it can be duplicated. It would cause a problem, if you would use subject as a foreign key, which in my example should not happen. Subject, at least in theory is just normal required field. Also, it does not have anything to do with joining table (`UserClaimRelation`) - it is not used there, only the ID's are stored there, by convention. Could it be that You did not apply migration or something similar? A database tables already exists and changes in code are not reflected in DB?

Answer (score 0):

I applied the code. Tables created like below image. But when I **try to update an userA's subject with userB's Subject** (same claims of userB) I got the below error

[image: table]

Updating [image: updating got error]

SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UserClaimRelation'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserClaimRelation'. The duplicate key value is (bd7eb87f-2a5f-4921-758e-08d9b97d3121, 13229d33-99e0-41b3-b18d-4f72127e3971). bcos its trying to insert in UserClaimRelation, same as the profiler query I given initially.