# EF core issue in inserting

Tags: entity-framework-core, insert, many-to-many

I have some doubt on entity framwork. I have two classes User and UserClaim. When I run migration there are 3 tables created, User, UserClaim and UserUserClaim.

1. Is the new table UserUserClaim created by EF (columns UserId, ClaimId) bcos to maintain the relationship I guess. **Am I correct?**
2. When inserting User with UserClaims the values will be automatically added to the table UserUserClaim  but when I add UserClaims only the **values are not added**, why it is so?
3. Is it possible **not to create table UserUserClaim** ?

   ```
        public class User{

        [Key]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid Subject { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; set; } = new List<UserClaim>();

    }


    public class UserClaim 
    {

        [Key]
        public Guid UserClaimId { get; set; } 

        [MaxLength(250)]
        [Required]
        public string Type{ get; set; } 

        [Required]
        public Guid Subject { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(250)]
        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
   ```

**migration code**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserUserClaim",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ClaimsUserClaimId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                UsersUserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserUserClaim", x => new { x.ClaimsUserClaimId, x.UsersUserId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserUserClaim_UserClaims_ClaimsUserClaimId",
                    column: x => x.ClaimsUserClaimId,
                    principalTable: "UserClaims",
                    principalColumn: "UserClaimId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserUserClaim_Users_UsersUserId",
                    column: x => x.UsersUserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "UserId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, EF will automatically create said table for many-to-many relationships - users can have many claims, claim can be assigned to many users.
2 - You are adding a user and claims that are in relationship with said user - therefore this is reflected in the `UserUserClaim` table. Adding new claim does not create new relationship. If You'll add this new claim later to a user, entry will be made.
3 - No - said table always will be created when relation is many-to-many. You can only reconfigure its naming / keys etc. like this (more or less, example from my app):

```cs
builder.HasMany(x => x.Seasons)
                .WithMany(x => x.DeparturePlans)
                .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                    "DeparturePlanSeason",
                    x => x.HasOne<Season>().WithMany(),
                    x => x.HasOne<DeparturePlan>().WithMany(),
                    x => x.ToTable("DeparturePlanSeason", "hub"));
```

This configures this third table for `many-to-many` relationship for entities called `Season` and `DeparturePlan` to be named "DeparturePlanSeason" in custom schema "hub".

Comment: thanks for the clarification but if you notice the code ,I am trying to make a relationship using Subject instead of userid. So that means many users will have same subject based on assignment. For example userA, UserB will have the same subject so the claims also will be same for both. Basically trying to avoid duplicate users based on certain conditions

Comment: The problem is, UserA , UserB created and assigned the different claims. No issue at all. When assigning existing claims (for example UserB's claims are assigned to UserA's claims) then I while deleting UserB's calim by subjectId is creating the primary key duplicate issue error. I have posted a new [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199503/ef6-many-to-many-can-not-delete)